# OpenShift Django/Python site cannot be reached ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED

Tags: openshift

I just created a new account on OpenShift to test out some coding I'd like to do. 
I created one python app and it was working, but then when creating a DjangoApp and accessing the standard url, I got ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED error. 
Does anyone know if I'm doing something wrong or what this could be related to?
Cheers
Doug

Comment: pythonapp-dougscloud.rhcloud.com is the link if anyone wanted to know

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you re-used the application name (deleted the old application and created a new one with the same name) it could take up to 24 hours for the dns to be routed to the correct server.  if you are going to do rapid create/delete/create cycles, you should use different application names so that you don't have to wait on DNS updates.

Comment: ok, that could have been it. Seems its working somewhat now without having done anything :D thanks!